# "temporary value dropped while borrowed" with capturing closure

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime, borrow-checker, trait-objects

Please consider the following example ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6ad8cf8d5f3755aedd4409cf5ac21b0f)):

```rust
struct Animal<'a> {
    format: &'a dyn Fn() -> (),
}

impl <'a>Animal<'a> {
    pub fn set_formatter(&mut self, _fmt: &'a dyn Fn() -> ()) -> () {} // Getting rid of 'a here satisfies the compiler
    pub fn bark(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut dog: Animal = Animal { format: &|| {()} };
    let x = 0;
    dog.set_formatter(&|| {
        println!("{}", x); // Commenting this out gets rid of the error. Why?
    });
    dog.bark(); // Commenting this out gets rid of the error. Why?
}
```

This gives the following compilation error:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:13:24
   |
13 |       dog.set_formatter(&|| {
   |  ________________________^
14 | |         println!("{}", x); // Commenting this out gets rid of the error. Why?
15 | |     });
   | |     ^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   | |_____|
   |       creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
16 |       dog.bark(); // Commenting this out gets rid of the error. Why?
   |       --- borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0716`.
error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

This kind of makes sense as the closure that I'm passing to `dog.set_formatter(...)` is indeed a temporary which (I guess) is freed when execution proceeds to `dog.bark();`.

I know that getting rid of the explicit lifetime annotation in the implementation of `set_formatter` seems to satisfy the compiler (note the missing `'a` before `dyn`):

```rust
pub fn set_formatter(&mut self, _fmt: & dyn Fn() -> ()) -> () {}
```

However, I don't understand the following:

1. Why does the problem go away when I comment out `println!("{}", x);` inside the closure? I'm still passing a temporary which I expect the compiler to complain about, but it doesn't.
2. Why does the problem go away when I comment out `dog.bark();` at the end? Again, I'm still passing a temporary closure which is freed but now the compiler is happy. Why?

Comment: I asked a concise Question for common rust error `error[E0716]` [error E0716: temporary value dropped while borrowed (rust)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71626083/error-e0716-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed-rust). It links back to this Question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that `&|| ()` has a `'static` lifetime:

```rust
fn main() {
    let closure: &'static dyn Fn() = &|| (); // compiles
}
```

Another thing worth mentioning is that a closure's lifetime cannot exceed the lifetime of any of the variables it captures from its environment, which is why if we try to pass a non-static variable to our static closure it would fail to compile:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x = 0; // non-static temporary variable
    let closure: &'static dyn Fn() = &|| {
        println!("{}", x); // x reference captured by closure
    }; // error: trying to capture non-static variable in static closure
}
```

We'll come back to that. Anyway, so if I have a struct which is generic over references, and I pass it a `'static` reference, I'll have a `'static` instance of that struct:

```rust
struct Dog<'a> {
    format: &'a dyn Fn(),
}

fn main() {
    let dog: Dog<'static> = Dog { format: &|| () }; // compiles
}
```

The second thing to understand is once you instantiate a type you cannot change it. This includes any of its generic parameters, including lifetimes. Once you have a `Dog<'static>` it will *always* be a `Dog<'static>`, you cannot convert it into a `Dog<'1>` for some anonymous lifetime `'1` that is shorter than `'static`.

This has some strong implications, one of which is that your `set_formatter` method probably doesn't behave how you think it behaves. Once you have a `Dog<'static>` you can *only* pass `'static` formatters to `set_formatter`. The method looks like this:

```rust
impl<'a> Dog<'a> {
    fn set_formatter(&mut self, _fmt: &'a dyn Fn()) {}
}
```

But since we know we're working with a `Dog<'static>` we can substitute out the generic lifetime parameter `'a` with `'static` to see what we're really working with:

```rust
// what the impl would be for Dog<'static>
impl Dog {
    fn set_formatter(&mut self, _fmt: &'static dyn Fn()) {}
}
```

So now that we've gotten all of that context out of the way let's get to your actual questions.

> Why does the problem go away when I comment out `println!("{}", x);` inside the closure? I'm still passing a temporary which I expect the compiler to complain about, but it doesn't.

Why it fails, with comments:

```rust
struct Dog<'a> {
    format: &'a dyn Fn(),
}

impl<'a> Dog<'a> {
    fn set_formatter(&mut self, _fmt: &'a dyn Fn()) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut dog: Dog<'static> = Dog { format: &|| () };
    
    // x is a temporary value on the stack with a non-'static lifetime
    let x = 0;
    
    // this closure captures x by reference which ALSO gives it a non-'static lifetime
    // and you CANNOT pass a non-'static closure to a Dog<'static>
    dog.set_formatter(&|| {
        println!("{}", x); 
    });
}
```

The reason this error is "fixed" by commenting out the line `println!("{}", x);` is because it gives the closure a `'static` lifetime again since it no longer borrows the non-`'static` variable `x`.

> Why does the problem go away when I comment out `dog.bark();` at the end? Again, I'm still passing a temporary closure which is freed but now the compiler is happy. Why?

This weird edge case only seems to happen when we don't explicitly type-annotate the `dog` variable with `Dog<'static>`. When a variable doesn't have an explicit type annotation the compiler attempts to infer its type, but it does so lazily, and tries to be as flexible as possible, giving the benefit of the doubt to the programmer, in order to make the code compile. It *really should* throw a compile error even without the `dog.bark()` but it doesn't for whatever mysterious reasons. The point is it's not the `dog.bark()` line that is making the code fail to compile, it should be failing to compile at the `set_formatter` line regardless, but for whatever reason the compiler doesn't bother to throw an error until you try to use `dog` again after that offending line. Even just dropping `dog` will trigger the error:

```rust
struct Dog<'a> {
    format: &'a dyn Fn(),
}

impl<'a> Dog<'a> {
    fn set_formatter(&mut self, _fmt: &'a dyn Fn()) {}
}

fn main() {
    let mut dog = Dog { format: &|| () };
    let x = 0;
    
    dog.set_formatter(&|| {
        println!("{}", x); 
    });
    
    drop(dog); // triggers "temp freed" error above
}
```

And since we've come this far, let's answer your unofficial third question, paraphrased by me:

> Why does getting rid of the `'a` in the `set_formatter` method satisfy the compiler?

Because it changes what is effectively this for `Dog<'static>`:

```rust
// what the impl would be for Dog<'static>
impl Dog {
    fn set_formatter(&mut self, _fmt: &'static dyn Fn()) {}
}
```

Into this:

```rust
// what the impl would now be for Dog<'static>
impl Dog {
    fn set_formatter(&mut self, _fmt: &dyn Fn()) {}
}
```

So now you can pass non-`'static` closures to a `Dog<'static>` although it's pointless since the method doesn't actually do anything, and the compiler will complain again the moment you actually try to set the closure in the `Dog<'static>` struct.